# how to stop a loop, outside of the loop?

Tags: python, loops, try-catch, except

So I've got a for loop that does something, and I'm required to make a try-except statement above (used in opening a file, exception if file not found), however I get a syntax error with the for loop below it (though it does give me the exception message when I pick the wrong file). How could I stop the program from running the loop after I've gotten an exception?

I think using break might have something to do with it but not quite sure how. I'm thinking something along the lines of if my exception message is printed then break or something like that. This is the code in question:

```
def getIngredients(path, basename):
  ingredient = []
  filename = path + '\\' + basename
  try:
    file = open(filename, "r")
  except:
    printNow("File not found.")

  for item in file: 
    if item.find("name") > -1:
      startindex = item.find("name") + 5
      endindex = item.find("<//name>") - 7
      ingredients = item[startindex:endindex]
      ingredient.append(ingredients)

  del ingredient[0]
  del ingredient[4]


  for item in ingredient:
    printNow(item)
```

Basically, because I picked the wrong file to get the exception, the for loop underneath which uses the file gives me an error.

Comment: You'll need to post the code (copy it into your question, highlight it and press Ctrl-K) if you want us to find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: yes, please paste code... sounds to me like you need to add a line in your while loop that searches for that error.  and once it finds it, you break the loop from within.

Comment: BTW, Python uses 4 characters of indentation as per [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: He's not the only one who uses two spaces in open defiance of PEP-8.

Answer (score 1):

Well, *you* need to decide what you want to happen if the file is not found.

You could choose to simply return from the function:

```
def getIngredients(path, basename):
    ingredient = []
    filename = path + '\\' + basename
    try:
        file = open(filename, "r")
    except IOError:                 # Never use a bare "except"! Be specific!
        printNow("File not found.")
        return

    for item in file: 
        ...

    return ingredient
```

That way, the caller can check from the return value whether the function completed successfully (if that matters):

- If an error occurred before the loop was run, `None` is returned.
- If the loop doesn't find any matches, an empty list `[]` is returned.
- Otherwise, the list of results is returned.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, every time you hit an exception you set a `flag` variable to `1` (or `true`).  Then simply envelop your `loop` around an `if-statement` - `if` the `flag` is set, then don't execute the `loop`, otherwise, execute it.

Alternatively, if you (for some reason) do need to enter the loop, then you could choose to have the `if clause` inside the loop and use the `break` statement to break out of or exit the loop.

More information about the [break statement in python](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/break.html), and an example of how to [use it within a loop](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5/tut/node23.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `break` while on `except` in a loop, to come out of it.

```
>>> while True:  
...     try:  
...         x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))  
...     except ValueError:  
...         print "Oops! That was no valid number. Try again..."  
...         break  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to exit the function if the file is wrong. Then this will do it:

```
except:
  printNow("File not found.")
  return
```

Comment: although i dont understand why return ends it? and break does not?

Comment: `break` aborts a running `for` or `while` loop. `return` is used to exit a function.